# Ruby errors when installing vcap/cloudfoundry

Tags: ruby, cloud-foundry

I downloaded vcap_dev_setup and ran it on my local server with a -D option to specify a custom hostname.

The installation went well, no error messages.

However, when starting cloudfoundry, I get a lot of error messages like these:

```
ladmin@sky:~/cloudfoundry$ /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/bin/vcap_dev start
Targeting deployment "devbox" with cloudfoundry home "/home/ladmin/cloudfoundry"
Setting up cloud controller environment
Setting up the uaa environment
Using cloudfoundry config from /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config
Executing /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/bin/vcap start cloud_controller router stager health_manager dea uaa redis_node mysql_node mongodb_node rabbitmq_node postgresql_node vblob_node redis_gateway mysql_gateway mongodb_gateway rabbitmq_gateway postgresql_gateway vblob_gateway -c /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config -v /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/vcap -l /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/log
DEPRECATION WARNING: Yajl's JSON gem compatibility API is going to be removed in 2.0
cloud_controller              :  STOPPED
LOG:
 /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/source.rb:572:in `rescue in load_spec_files': https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa.git (at 603bb76) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/source.rb:570:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/source.rb:385:in `local_specs'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/source.rb:555:in `specs'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:147:in `block in resolve'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:145:in `each'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:145:in `resolve'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:135:in `specs_for'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:124:in `requested_specs'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
    from /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/vcap/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/config/boot.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/vcap/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/bin/cloud_controller:27:in `<main>'
router                        :  RUNNING
stager                        :  STOPPED
LOG:
 /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/source.rb:572:in `rescue in load_spec_files': https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-staging.git (at bf84426) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/source.rb:570:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/source.rb:385:in `local_specs'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/source.rb:555:in `specs'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:147:in `block in resolve'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:145:in `each'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:145:in `resolve'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:135:in `specs_for'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:124:in `requested_specs'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
    from /home/ladmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
    from /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/vcap/stager/bin/stager:5:in `<main>'
health_manager                :  STOPPED
```

When checking status after startup this is the output:

```
ladmin@sky:~/cloudfoundry$ /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/bin/vcap_dev status
Targeting deployment "devbox" with cloudfoundry home "/home/ladmin/cloudfoundry"
Setting up cloud controller environment
Setting up the uaa environment
Using cloudfoundry config from /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config
Executing /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/bin/vcap status cloud_controller router stager health_manager dea uaa redis_node mysql_node mongodb_node rabbitmq_node postgresql_node vblob_node redis_gateway mysql_gateway mongodb_gateway rabbitmq_gateway postgresql_gateway vblob_gateway -c /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config -v /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/vcap -l /home/ladmin/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/log
DEPRECATION WARNING: Yajl's JSON gem compatibility API is going to be removed in 2.0
cloud_controller              :  STOPPED
router                        :  RUNNING
stager                        :  STOPPED
health_manager                :  STOPPED
dea                           :  RUNNING
uaa                           :  RUNNING
redis_node                    :  STOPPED
mysql_node                    :  STOPPED
mongodb_node                  :  STOPPED
rabbitmq_node                 :  STOPPED
postgresql_node               :  STOPPED
vblob_node                    :  STOPPED
redis_gateway                 :  STOPPED
mysql_gateway                 :  STOPPED
mongodb_gateway               :  STOPPED
rabbitmq_gateway              :  STOPPED
postgresql_gateway            :  STOPPED
vblob_gateway                 :  STOPPED
```

My installation looks like this:

```
ladmin@sky:~/cloudfoundry/vcap$ ll
total 332
drwxr-xr-x 16 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x  4 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:02 ../
drwxr-xr-x 11 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:00 acm/
-rw-r--r--  1 ladmin ladmin   1990 2013-08-05 11:00 AUTHORS
drwxr-xr-x  3 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:00 bin/
drwxr-xr-x  6 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:00 cloud_controller/
drwxr-xr-x  8 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:01 dea/
drwxr-xr-x  7 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:00 dev_setup/
drwxr-xr-x  2 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:00 docs/
drwxr-xr-x  3 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:00 git/
drwxr-xr-x  8 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:00 .git/
-rw-r--r--  1 ladmin ladmin    144 2013-08-05 11:00 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 ladmin ladmin    703 2013-08-05 11:00 .gitmodules
-rw-r--r--  1 ladmin ladmin 242998 2013-08-05 11:00 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 ladmin ladmin    484 2013-08-05 11:00 NOTICE
-rw-r--r--  1 ladmin ladmin    688 2013-08-05 11:00 Rakefile
drwxr-xr-x  2 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:00 rakelib/
-rw-r--r--  1 ladmin ladmin   6620 2013-08-05 11:00 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  8 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:01 router/
drwxr-xr-x 22 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:01 services/
drwxr-xr-x  8 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:01 stager/
drwxr-xr-x 10 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:01 tests/
drwxr-xr-x 12 ladmin ladmin   4096 2013-08-05 11:02 uaa/
```

And other than the vcap and .deployments folder the cloudfoundry folder is empty. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dev_setup` is no longer supported or maintained, and only targets the old v1 environment. You should look at using `cf-vagrant-installer` or `nise-bosh` for Cloud Foundry v2.

Answer (score 0):

I had to go through the folders for mysql, redis etc and run bundle install.. Seems like an error in the installation script.